# Autotools not installing directories (appends ./ to directories only)

Tags: c, linux, autotools

I am working with autotools to install several doc directories, however, it is adding an unneeded prefix to the directories in question:

I run

```
autoreconf -f;automake; ./configure; make; sudo make install
```

Error:

```
test -z "/usr/local/share/opendiameter/docs" || /bin/mkdir -p "/usr/local/share/opendiameter/docs"
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 docs/msvc-solution-usage.txt docs/development_policy.txt docs/coding_style.txt docs/bugtracking-diagram.pdf ./docs/framework/ ./docs/libdiameter ./docs/libdiametereap ./docs/libdiameternasreq ./docs/libdiametermip4 ./docs/libeap ./docs/libpana ./docs/nasreq opendiameter.kdevelop tools/getopt.patch tools/getopt1.patch autogen.sh RELEASE README '/usr/local/share/opendiameter/docs'
/usr/bin/install: omitting directory `./docs/framework/'
/usr/bin/install: omitting directory `./docs/libdiameter'
/usr/bin/install: omitting directory `./docs/libdiametereap'
/usr/bin/install: omitting directory `./docs/libdiameternasreq'
/usr/bin/install: omitting directory `./docs/libdiametermip4'
/usr/bin/install: omitting directory `./docs/libeap'
/usr/bin/install: omitting directory `./docs/libpana'
/usr/bin/install: omitting directory `./docs/nasreq'
</code>
```

And here is the `Makefile.am` - NOTE that I have tried  `$(top_srcdir)` as a prefix to the `docs/`

```
docdir = $(prefix)/share/opendiameter/docs
doc_DATA = docs/msvc-solution-usage.txt \
    docs/development_policy.txt \
    docs/coding_style.txt \
    docs/bugtracking-diagram.pdf \
    docs/framework/ \
    docs/libdiameter \
    docs/libdiametereap \
    docs/libdiameternasreq \
    docs/libdiametermip4 \
    docs/libeap \
    docs/libpana \
    docs/nasreq \
    opendiameter.kdevelop \
    tools/getopt.patch \
    tools/getopt1.patch \
    autogen.sh \
    RELEASE \
    README

SUBDIRS_LIBS = libodutl \
               libdiamparser \
           libdiameter \
           libdiametermip4 \
           libeap \
           libpana \
           libdiametereap \
           libdiameternasreq

SUBDIRS_APPS = applications
SUBDIRS_DOCS = docs

SUBDIRS = $(SUBDIRS_LIBS) $(SUBDIRS_APPS)
DIST_SUBDIRS = $(SUBDIRS_LIBS) $(SUBDIRS_APPS) $(SUBDIRS_DOCS)

includedir = $(prefix)/include/opendiameter
include_HEADERS = $(top_srcdir)/include/framework.h \
                  $(top_srcdir)/include/aaa_parser_api.h \
                  $(top_srcdir)/include/aaa_global_config.h \
                  $(top_srcdir)/include/aaa_dictionary_api.h \
                  $(top_srcdir)/include/aaa_parser_defs.h \
                  $(top_srcdir)/include/resultcodes.h

dist-hook:
    rm -rf `find $(distdir) -name CVS`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assuming that `_DATA` knows how to deal with directories.  It does not.  It deals with files.

I'm assuming that you want the directory structure kept in the install.

In order to layout a directory structure you'll need to do something like this for each directory:

```
docdir = $(datadir)/opendiameter/docs
docframeworkdir = $(docdir)/framework

dist_doc_DATA = docs/msvc-solution-usage.txt \
...

dist_docframework_DATA = \
docs/framework/foo \
docs/framework/bar
```

Basically, you need to create a destination installation directory (like `docframeworkdir`)
and list out the files in it (like `dist_docframework_DATA`).  If the toplevel (e.g. `docs/framework`) directories also contain directories (e.g. `docs/framework/nest`), you'll need to create destinations for those also if the have files you want to install.

If this is too tedious, you can write an [install data hook](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Extending.html) to copy directories, which might be easier.

If you *don't* want the directory structure, you can add the list of files in `docs` to `dist_doc_DATA`.  You can also write an install data hook for this as well.

Comment: I went with creating the directory structure in the more tedious fashion.  Thanks!